Error trying to connect Blazor-app to WebAPI
I have a Blazor Client App which should connect to a WebAPI. Both hosted on Azure.
When I try to connect from the app to the API I get the following message:

Access to fetch at
'https://musicandbooksapplicationserverapim.azure-api.net/Authentication/login'
from origin 'https://musicandbooksapplicationserver.azurewebsites.net'
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your
needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with
CORS disabled.

In my azure when I look at the API, I see the following:


<policies>    
>         <!-- Throttle, authorize, validate, cache, or transform the requests -->    
>         <inbound>
>            <base />
>            <cors allow-credentials="true">            
>                <allowed-origins>                                   <origin><the origin of my requests></origin>            
>                </allowed-origins> 
>                <allowed-methods>                
>                    <method>[allow all methods]</method>            
>                </allowed-methods>        
>            </cors>     
>         </inbound>
>     <!-- Control if and how the requests are forwarded to services  -->    
>     <backend>
>         <base />
>     </backend>
>     <!-- Customize the responses -->    
>     <outbound>        
>         <base />
>     </outbound>
>     <!-- Handle exceptions and customize error responses  -->
>     <on-error>
>         <base />
>     </on-error> </policies>

So I think it should work. What am I missing?
